# Drawing a Truth Table: $φ$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having some trouble drawing the truth table for:

$$φ = ((p ∨ q ∨ r) \implies (¬p ∧ r))$$

What is the significance of the $φ$ sign and how does it affect the truth table?

Comment: $\phi$ is just a symbol assigned to that statement. The truth table of $\phi$ is the truth table of $(p \vee q \vee r)\to(\neg p \wedge r)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\varphi$ is the name of the expression. It doesn't really affect the truth table. At least not the actual content, it **could** affect it in that you can now write $\varphi$ as title (above the column) instead of $((p\lor q\lor r)\rightarrow (\neg p\lor r))$.